# Excel creating weird diagrams

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a list of times in one column. They are formatted as Time cells. When I simply select the values and click `Insert -> Line` (diagram), I can't seem to get the right kind of diagram.

[image]

What causes this?

Comment: You only have 1 column and no data range. What did you expect?

Comment: There has to be something else wrong too. Checking the sum of the seven first results in 15:30.

Comment: even if formatted as time, it the value might include a date - and if that differs by a day, this might explain the strange outlier. for test purposes, change the format to date with time and see if the days are different...